# Nearest Neighbour Classifier for multiple features

Tags: matlab, classification, nearest-neighbor, feature-selection

I have a dataset set that looks like this:

```
   Feature 1    Feature 2    Feature 3    Feature 4    Feature 5    Class
Obj    2           2            2            8            5           1
Obj    2           8            3            3            4           2
Obj    1           7            4            4            8           1
Obj    4           3            5            9            7           2
```

The rows contain objects, which have a number of features. I have put 5 features for demonstration purposes but there is approximately 50 features per object, with the final column being the class label for each object.

I want to create and run the nearest neighbour classifier algorithm on this data set and retrieve the error rate.I have managed to get the NN algorithm working for each feature, a short Pseudo code example is below. For each feature I loop through each object, assigning object j according to its nearest neighbours.

```
for i = 1:Number of features
    for j = 1:Number of objects
        distance between data(j,i) and values of feature i
        order by shortest distance
        sum or the class labels k shortest distances 
        assign class with largest number of labels
    end
    error = mean(labels~=assigned)
end
```

The issue I have is how would I work out the 1-NN algorithm for multiple features. I will have a selection of the features from my dataset say features 1,2 and 3. I want to calculate the error rate if I add feature 5 into my set of selected features. I want to work out the error using 1NN. Would I find the nearest value out of all my features 1-3 in my selected feature?

For example, for my data set above:

Adding feature 5 - For object 1 of feature 5 the closest number to that is object 4 of feature 3. As this has a class label of 2 I will assign object 1 of feature 5 the class 2. This is obviously a misclassification but I would continue to classify all other objects in Feature 5 and compare the assigned and actual values.

Is this the correct way to perform the 1NN against multiple features?